# How much blood is needed to forge a sword?

Tags: biology, hard-science, biochemistry

Blood of most vertebrates contains hemoglobin, which contains iron. I've imagined a world where someone once had a seemingly stupid idea of using blood as a source of iron.

Now, the world is analogous to Earth pre-firearms Middle Ages (but with magic and dragons) and iron ore availability is the same too, i.e. quite enough. However, it turned out the blood iron has magic properties, which the usual metals most unfortunately lack. Actually, before this invention no one was able to enchant any mundane weapon or piece of armor, and battle magic as a whole is nonexistent. The mage-smiths who create this weapons are called "bloodforgers".

For now, the blood iron is mostly used to create swords and daggers. Its properties depend on source creature; each case needs unique spells to unlock the hidden properties. I can imagine three most important cases:

1. Dragon blood. The dragon must be slain in  honest heroic battle. The sword will be fiery and will easily hack through thickest armor. Even a frail teenager can easily split a full-plated knight with its horse in two with it, and they will be instantly roasted to "well done".
2. Blood of innocents. Innocents should better be humans or unicorns, but puppies will suffice for weaker effect. They must be brutally killed, no mere bloodletting will do. The blade is no better than usual to cut through armor and bones. But when it touches flesh, it bites into it on itself, leaving deep wounds, and the bleeding is very hard or (if the victims were innocent enough) to stop. Favored by assassins.
3. Wielder's blood. A dedicated warrior "donates" their blood repeatedly to create a weapon which is literally and extension of the arm. It feels the owner's intention and strikes with supernatural precision, it can even bend and become thinner to pass through the smallest holes in armor, and then it aims to the most critical organ within its reach, so it would never miss the heart or major artery by couple of inches.

The bloodforgers are trying to unlock any special properties in blood from such abundant sources as fallen warriors left on battlefields and slaughtered farm animals, but without success for now.

---

**(Skip until here if you're not into fluff)**

And now the hard part. I need to calculate how much blood is needed for a sword. No magic here, iron atoms won't pop out from nowhere.

This needs the following values:

1. Mass fraction of iron in hemoglobin
2. Hemoglobin content in blood (mass of hemoglobin per volume of blood)
3. Total volume of blood in the body, or, for case 3, the amount of blood which can be donated safely per year.

Humans have the same physiology as in real world. Smallest dragons are of full-grown T. rex's size, largest - of Argentinosaurus's. Hemoglobin count in dragons is similar to large land mammals, or, more precisely, giraffes. Unicorns are just horses with a horn.

So, how many dragons or innocents do I need to slay, or can I donate enough blood in my lifetime?

Comment: @0celouvsky While the world is fantasy, the question itself concerns only real-world biochemistry, and I want the answer to be backed by sources. You may scroll to the bottom of the question to get straight to hard-science part (beginning with "And now the hard part").

Comment: I'm almost sure I've seen a question about extracting iron from blood already. Sadly, can't find it now.

Comment: That's a lot of words just to ask for a simple number that you can get via Google.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  And, **good show** in reading the tag description and flagging for [tag:hard-science] as you posted.

Comment: @Neith I've been so free to add a section marker so people that do not have attention spans long enough to read the whole thing can skip the fluff and get to the sciency part immediately :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it asks for hard-science but does not provide enough information to be answered as it described in [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-science/info).

Comment: @MolbOrg I really don't know what else you want... the question spells everything out.

Comment: @Azuaron do not get me wrong - it is ok question if it would be science-based, and is not bad question in general. The accepted answer is also fine answer for the science-based question(but it could be a bit better). Different animals have different concentrations of hemoglobin in the blood. As an example [sperm whale](http://uk.whales.org/blog/2012/10/how-do-whales-breathe). Approximating a dragon with dinos is totally incorrect. Dragon is also not a scaled up pterodactyl. A good answer would at least try to estimate dragon blood composition, which will be a pure speculation. and so on.

Comment: @MolbOrg Except science-based questions have the same basic requirements as hard-science questions, it's just that the _answers_ don't require citations.

Comment: @Azuaron Exactly, this is the point. "Questions with this tag should be answered, as far as _possible_, based on known scientific facts or reasonable extrapolations from those". If it is not possible you feel free to imply whatever you need if you stay in the realm of known science. There is no data to give hard-science answer, but science-based answer can be given. It forbids only pseudoscience and magic. IDK - some of my rambling about HS on meta https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/20315 And take look at the answer - it just schools homework.

Comment: @MolbOrg My point is that the only difference between a _science-based_ question and a _hard-science_ question is the form the _answers_ must take. Indeed, the _science-based_ tag says: "For questions that require answers **_based on hard science_**." (emphasis mine) Therefore, a question that's _not_ a valid _hard-science_ question because of insufficient information _is also **not** a valid_ science-based _question for the same reason_. Also, I don't know where you quote comes from; that's not on the tag.

Comment: @Azuaron My cite comes from the description of [science-based tag](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/science-based/info). I agree with your point(at least in the case) from the comment I'm answering now. "not a valid science-based question for the same reason" - not correct, and you will see that by reading the tag description.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This information [is a mere Google away](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=iron%20content%20of%20blood). The [top result from that mere Google](http://www.jbc.org/content/104/1/157.full.pdf) tells us that blood contains around 0.5g iron per litre of blood.

[Another Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%20much%20blood%20does%20the%20body%20contain) tells us an adult human contains around 5 litres of blood, though obviously it depends on the size of the person. And lastly [there is no clear consensus on the amount of blood you can lose per day](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%20much%20blood%20can%20you%20safely%20lose%20a%20day), but a 400ml blood donation can be made every 2 or 3 months. For several years I gave blood four times a year without any obvious consequences.

According to Wikipedia, a [longsword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longsword) weighs 1.1kg to 1.8kg. Let's take 1.5kg as a nice middle value - assuming that you can forge the sword without wasting any iron, you're looking at 3,000 litres of blood, or all of the blood from 600 average human adults. If we're using 400 mL donations, you'd need 7,500.

Comment: so, how much blood he needs finally?? 100 liters? 500?

Comment: @maxkoryukov 3000 liters, actually, it says so in the answer if you'd actually read it

Comment: @pagie_ to be fair Ben edited that in after Max commented.

Comment: Now for answer to be complete only estimates for blood volume in T. rex and Argentinosaurus are needed.

Comment: @pagie_, actually yes, the answer was edited (https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/revisions/78885/2) and now it is much clearer (at least for me). Now I know, that a community with more than 7500 members can forge a sword in day even being closed in crystal clean room.

Answer (score -2):

2788 liters of human blood for 1.5 kg of iron

Comment: To be more specific: this is a hard-science question, so you can't just pluck a number out of thin air. You need evidence to back up your answer. How did you come to this conclusion? You need to edit that into your answer; at the moment, it's going to get deleted.